# "TypeError: undefined is not an object" while trying to test service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple service here that I'm testing and keep receiving the above error. Done a lot of research and know I have something that is null in my code but I can't find it. Thoughts? Thanks in advance :)

Config.js

```
'use strict';    

angular.module('App').service('configService', function(
  $rootScope, $http) {
  var configObj = null;
  return {

    getConfig: function() {
      if (configObj != null) {
        console.log("returning cached config");
        return configObj;
      }
      else {
        $http.get('conf.json').then(function(res) {
          $http.get(res.confLocation).then(function(
            locationResponse) {
            configObj = locationResponse;
            $rootScope.configObj = configObj;
            console.log($rootScope.configObj);
            return configObj;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

ConfigTest.js

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: configService', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('App'));

  var configService, $httpBackend, results;
  var tstConfig = {
    "confLocation": "local-dev-conf.json"
  };
  var tstConfigObj = {
    "AWS": {
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:8133"
    }
  };

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function(_configService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    inject(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.USERNAME = 'TESTER';
      $rootScope.configObj = tstConfigObj;
    });

    configService = configService;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    // backend definition common for all tests
    $httpBackend.expectGET('conf.json').respond(tstConfig);
    $httpBackend.expectGET('local-dev-conf.json').respond(tstConfigObj);
  }));

  it('it should do something', inject(function() {

    results = configService.getConfig().then(function() { //ERROR HERE

      // What should I be expecting to check if it's parsing the file?
      // expect(configFile).toEqual("Object{AWS: Object{region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8133'}}")

      console.log(results);
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
```

Comment: the line of code `configService = configService;` should be `configService = _configService_;`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, unfortunately I am getting the same error.

"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'configService.getConfig().then') (line 83)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your spec/testcase file. You need to assign *configService* to `configService`. Instead you're assigning `configService` to `configService`.

Also since you're calling the `getConfig` method from your `it` block, I suggest you `spyOn` it. But you don't have a spy on it. And it should also return a function named `then`. Since you don't have that, that's why you're getting an undefined error.

Following is something for your reference:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: configService', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('App'));

  var configService, $httpBackend, results;
  var tstConfig = {
    "confLocation": "local-dev-conf.json"
  };
  var tstConfigObj = {
    "AWS": {
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:8133"
    }
  };

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function(_configService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    inject(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.USERNAME = 'TESTER';
      $rootScope.configObj = tstConfigObj;
    });

    configService = _configService_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    // backend definition common for all tests
    $httpBackend.expectGET('conf.json').respond(tstConfig);
    $httpBackend.expectGET('local-dev-conf.json').respond(tstConfigObj);

    spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.callFake(function(){
        return{
            then: function(){
                return "something";
            }
        }
    });

  }));

    it('it should do something', inject(function() {

        results = configService.getConfig().then(function() { //ERROR HERE

          // What should I be expecting to check if it's parsing the file?
          // expect(configFile).toEqual("Object{AWS: Object{region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8133'}}")

          console.log(results);
        });
        //$httpBackend.flush();
    }));

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not returning the promise in the `else` statement of `config.js`

```
'use strict';    

angular.module('App').service('configService', function(
  $rootScope, $http) {
  var configObj = null;
  return {

    getConfig: function() {
      if (configObj != null) {
        console.log("returning cached config");
        return configObj;
      }
      else {
        // return the promise here
        return $http.get('conf.json').then(function(res) {
          $http.get(res.confLocation).then(function(
            locationResponse) {
            configObj = locationResponse;
            $rootScope.configObj = configObj;
            console.log($rootScope.configObj);
            return configObj;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

You forgot to return the promise, so the function was returning `undefined` which is "not an object" and has no `.then`